# How fix errors in csv file using rule sets?

Tags: validation, csv, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I would like to check a csv file containing approximately 20 columns by 100 rows for errors before importing into our database. New spreadsheets are received several times a month. Manually checking errors or dealing with errors missed in the manual checks is a problem.

Each csv file may contain a variety of errors -- different types in different columns.

For example, the FirstName column may contain capitalization errors or contain job titles or locations rather than names. (e.g. Manager, Office, Front Desk, Admin, etc.)

Email addresses and Web site urls may contain commas, spaces, etc. that create import errors.

Product categories may have capitalization errors or incorrect values leading to categorization errors in reports.

Is there a Mac-compatible tool that might allow me to create and update a set of rules that can be applied to each column in the csv file?

Might this be possible using a google apps script?

Ideally, I would like the ability to add new types of errors as we find them and run these rules against new files as they are received.

Does this type of product exist that is either mac-compatible or browser-based?

Any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I dont believe there is any such product readily available out there that caters to this specific requirement of yours. I would suggest you to post this request on a website such as 
[odesk](https://www.odesk.com) or [elance](https://www.elance.com) and you can commision one of the professionals there to develop this tool for you in Google Apps Script on top of Google Spreadsheets.